# bokeh select widget datetime inconsistency (pandas)

Tags: pandas, datetime, bokeh

I have a dataframe full of dates and transactions:

```
ENTRYDATE | TRANSACTIONS
2017-01-02   20
2017-01-16   51
..
2018-02-01   12
```

I have a select widget where the user can view the data by `['day,'weekly','monthly',annually]`

When `daily` or `annually` is chosen, the plot accurately update and summarizes the data into daily or annual transactions. However, when `weekly` or `monthly` is selected, it seems that plot bundles the `transactions` from Jan 2018 and Feb 2018 into 2017 Jan and Feb data, overstating 2017 counts. Why is this happening? How can I repair it?

Here is the relevant piece of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,DatetimeTickFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter, HoverTool, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc

df2=df[['ENTRYDATE']] 
df2['ENTRYDATE']=pd.to_datetime(df2['ENTRYDATE'],infer_datetime_format=True)

#set data sources
dfdate=(df2.groupby([df2['ENTRYDATE'].dt.date]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))
dfweek=(df2.groupby([df2['ENTRYDATE'].dt.week]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))
dfmonth=(df2.groupby([df2['ENTRYDATE'].dt.month]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))
dfyear=(df2.groupby([df2['ENTRYDATE'].dt.year]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))

source1=ColumnDataSource(data=dfdate)
source2=ColumnDataSource(data=dfweek)

p=figure(plot_width=800,plot_height=500, y_axis_label="Count")

p.line(x="ENTRYDATE",y="Transactions",color='blue', source=source1)
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter()

#update function
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if new=='Daily':
        source1.data={"ENTRYDATE":dfdate["ENTRYDATE"],"Transactions":dfdate["Transactions"]}
    elif new=='Weekly':
        source1.data=source2.data
    elif new=='Monthly':
        source1.data={"ENTRYDATE":dfmonth["ENTRYDATE"],"Transactions":dfmonth["Transactions"]}
    elif new=='Annually':
        source1.data={"ENTRYDATE":dfyear["ENTRYDATE"],"Transactions":dfyear["Transactions"]}
#selecttool
select=Select(title='Choose Your Time Interval:', options=['Daily','Weekly','Monthly','Annually'], value='daily')
select.on_change('value',update_plot)
layout=row(select, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to prefix the year to the week or month number and then sort it ascending. 
`df['YearWk']=df['ENTRYDATE'].dt.strftime('%Y.%W')`